# Tomcat 9 Server not starting in Eclipse 4

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

After adding Tomcat Server 9.0 to Eclipse 4.23 on Windows 11 the server will not start. The following warning is written to the console:

'WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Users\david\Documents\ApplicationServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.60**lib**], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]'

Note that the directory path is: 'C:\Users\david\Documents\ApplicationServers\apache-tomcat-9.0.60'. It appears that '**lib**' is appended to the path.

I have looked at every configuration that I can think of and searched the internet and have not found a similar problem or solution. Have any of you experienced this or have a solution?

[Server Configuration Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umYW8.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: within your tomcat installation, there should be `lib` folder which seems to be missing. Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment > Add... > Apache -> Apache Tomcat 9.0 > Next > Browse... > select root folder for tomcat installation > JRE = Workbench default JRE > Finish

Comment: The 'lib' folder is not missing. The Tomcat server starts as expected and properly servers up the web app. This issue is isolated to Eclipse. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: I have exhaustively looked at every configuration file and setting. I have deleted the server and reconfigured it. It appears to me that [tomcat root]\lib  is needed, but the path does not include a "\" after 9.0.60 and before "lib". This makes the path invalid. Surely I am not the only one that has experienced this issue. WARNING: Problem with directory '[C:\Users\david\Documents\ApplicationServers\apache-tomcat-**9.0.60lib**], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false],' canRead: [false]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. While I am not sure why the working directory default is set to the value it is (see screenshot) or why the warning does not list the default path as the error, I changed the path to the Tomcat [root] and all is well now.

[Eclipse Tomcat Fix Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4n1t.jpg)

Thank you to everyone that offered suggestions and/or gave this thought.

Answer (score -1):

Did you configure tomcat with following steps?

For configuring the tomcat server in eclipse IDE;

```
click on servers tab at the bottom side of the IDE 
right click on blank area
New 
Servers 
choose tomcat then its version
next 
click on Browse button 
select the apache tomcat root folder previous to bin 
next 
add projects required 
Finish
```

Comment: Yes. This is exactly how the Tomcat server was added to Eclipse.